# How to send variable value from controller to another different view in cakephp3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.2

I have two controller and two view in my cakephp3.

My 1st controllers and views are:

```
1.importController.php , index.ctp;
```

And my 2nd controllers and views are:

```
2.titlesController.php , success.ctp;
```

Now I want to send variable value (such as $data=5)  from importController.php to success.ctp view.

Comment: $this->redirect(['controller'=>'titlesController', 'action'=>'success',   $this->request->data['Post']['id'], 'var' =>$uploadSuccess]); i want to use this...but i don't know retrive the data from var in success.ctp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Redirect

```
$this->redirect(['controller'=>'titlesController', 'action'=>'success', $variableValue]);//$variableValue any value you can send.
```

In titlesController

```
function success($data){
 $this->set('data',$data);
}
```

On success.ctp you can use $data